# What is meant by processedWithError in the report task manager?

Tags: java, druid

I already ingested the file into the druid, greatfully it shows the ingestion is success. However when I checked in the reports of the ingestion, there are all rows are processed with error yet the Datasource is display in the "Datasource" tab.

I have tried to minimise the rows from 20M to 20 rows only. Here is my configuration file:

```
"type" : "index",
  "spec" : {
    "ioConfig" : {
      "type" : "index",
      "firehose" : {
        "type" : "local",
        "baseDir" : "/home/data/Salutica",
      "filter" : "outDashboard2RawV3.csv"
      }
    },
    "dataSchema" : {
        "dataSource": "DaTRUE2_Dashboard_V3",
      "granularitySpec" : {
        "type" : "uniform",
        "segmentGranularity" : "WEEK",
        "queryGranularity" : "none",
        "intervals" : ["2017-05-08/2019-05-17"],
        "rollup" : false
      },
      "parser" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "parseSpec": {
          "format" : "csv",
           "timestampSpec" : {
            "column" : "Date_Time",
            "format" : "auto"
         },
        "columns" : [
          "Main_ID","Parameter_ID","Date_Time","Serial_Number","Status","Station_ID",
          "Station_Type","Parameter_Name","Failed_Date_Time","Failed_Measurement",
          "Database_Name","Date_Time_Year","Date_Time_Month",
          "Date_Time_Day","Date_Time_Hour","Date_Time_Weekday","Status_New"
        ],
        "dimensionsSpec" : {
          "dimensions" : [
              "Date_Time","Serial_Number","Status","Station_ID",
              "Station_Type","Parameter_Name","Failed_Date_Time",
              "Failed_Measurement","Database_Name","Status_New",
              {
                  "name" : "Main_ID",
                  "type" : "long"
              },
              {
                  "name" : "Parameter_ID",
                  "type" : "long"
              },
              {
                  "name" : "Date_Time_Year",
                  "type" : "long"
              },
              {
                  "name" : "Date_Time_Month",
                  "type" : "long"
              },
              {
                  "name" : "Date_Time_Day",
                  "type" : "long"
              },
              {
                  "name" : "Date_Time_Hour",
                  "type" : "long"
              },
              {
                  "name" : "Date_Time_Weekday",
                  "type" : "long"
              }
                  ]
           }
        }
      },
      "metricsSpec" : [
        {
          "name" : "count",
          "type" : "count"
        }
      ]
    },
    "tuningConfig" : {
      "type" : "index",
      "partitionsSpec" : {
        "type" : "hashed",
        "targetPartitionSize" : 5000000
      },
      "jobProperties" : {}
    }
  }
}
```

Report:

> {"ingestionStatsAndErrors":{"taskId":"index_DaTRUE2_Dashboard_V3_2019-09-10T01:16:47.113Z","payload":{"ingestionState":"COMPLETED","unparseableEvents":{},"rowStats":{"determinePartitions":{"processed":0,"processedWithError":0,"thrownAway":0,"unparseable":0},"buildSegments":{"processed":0,"**processedWithError**":20606701,"thrownAway":0,"unparseable":1}},"errorMsg":null},"type":"ingestionStatsAndErrors"}}

I'm expecting this:

> {"**processed":20606701**,"processedWithError":0,"thrownAway":0,"unparseable":1}},"errorMsg":null},"type":"ingestionStatsAndErrors"}}

instead of this:

> {"processed":0,"**processedWithError":20606701**,"thrownAway":0,"unparseable":1}},"errorMsg":null},"type":"ingestionStatsAndErrors"}}

Comment: Please provide example input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is my input data from csv;

```
    "Main_ID","Parameter_ID","Date_Time","Serial_Number","Status","Station_ID","Station_Type","Parameter_Name","Failed_Date_Time","Failed_Measurement","Database_Name","Date_Time_Year","Date_Time_Month","Date_Time_Day","Date_Time_Hour","Date_Time_Weekday","Status_New"
1,3,"2018-10-05 15:00:55","1840SDF00038","Passed","ST1","BLTBoard","1.8V","","","DaTRUE2Left",2018,10,5,15,"Friday","Passed"
1,4,"2018-10-05 15:00:55","1840SDF00038","Passed","ST1","BLTBoard","1.35V","","","DaTRUE2Left",2018,10,5,15,"Friday","Passed"
1,5,"2018-10-05 15:00:55","1840SDF00038","Passed","ST1","BLTBoard","Isc_VChrg","","","DaTRUE2Left",2018,10,5,15,"Friday","Passed"
1,6,"2018-10-05 15:00:55","1840SDF00038","Passed","ST1","BLTBoard","Isc_VBAT","","","DaTRUE2Left",2018,10,5,15,"Friday","Passed"
```